# Bootstrap scss glyphicons path error, missing backslash in path

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, jekyll, glyphicons

I've got a problem using glyphicons with a Jekyll website using Bootstrap scss. It seems to be generating the path incorrectly but I can't figure out where the problem is.

Jekyll gives the following error when I try to include a glyphicon

```
ERROR `/fonts/bootstrapglyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2' not found.
```

The path for the glyphicon font is wrong, its missing a '/' and should read

```
/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

I tried correcting this in the generated css file and it worked, so I'm now trying to find where the incorrect path is generated.

I've looked in the _glyphicons.scss file and the following code seems to be generating the path

```
@at-root {
  // Import the fonts
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    src: url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot'));
    src: url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot?#iefix'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype'),
         url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff2'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff2')) format('woff2'),
         url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.woff')) format('woff'),
         url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.ttf'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.ttf')) format('truetype'),
         url(if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, twbs-font-path('#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.svg##{$icon-font-svg-id}'), '#{$icon-font-path}#{$icon-font-name}.svg##{$icon-font-svg-id}')) format('svg');
  }
}
```

I've also looked in _variables.scss and found this

```
$icon-font-path: if($bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, "bootstrap/", "../fonts/bootstrap/") !default;
```

I can't see where the error is in the code. I'm not very familiar with scss, this is my first go. Can anyone point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem earlier and I overrode the path before importing bootstrap something like this. May not be desired answer but a workaround probably.

```
$icon-font-path: "fonts/bootstrap/" !default;
@import "_bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is often related to the loading order of the variables SCSS file. Look for the $icon-font-path in other parts of your file and check if the / is missing.

After that, change the content of the $icon-font-path to anything, to test if your file is being loaded, reread the error message to see if the path changed.

In the variables file, you have the $icon-font-path variable that is where bootstrap 3 will look for the glyphicons fonts. But when compiling this file, you need to load your variables.scss file before the bootstrap stylesheets.

Here is how the file order works in my case:

```
@import "variables";
@import '../bootstrap/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
```

Check if in your case the second line is coming before you variables, if yes, you have to change it to have the same order as mine.

This issue can be also related to the error message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found): glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

Answer (score 0):

for those who still have the problem try: in file: _variable.scss if you looked in line 83 the path (../fonts/bootstrap/) is not correct, since the font folder is not in the stylsheets folder, so you have to go back one step and then re-enter to the folder (fonts). so it will be necessary to change:

> line 83: add (../) so that it becomes:

```
> $ icon-font-path: if ($ bootstrap-sass-asset-helper, "bootstrap /","../../fonts/bootstrap/")! default;
```